# Error using For Loop when no comma in the column value

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Situation 1**

```
num_word = []
for num in (data_negative['Comments'].str.split()):
  num_word.append(num)
  print(num_word)
```

[image: result for num_word]

I have applied this code to get the number of words in *Comments* column, it shows the message so I think the data is too big and I tried to do it by having the first 4 items

**Situation 2**

```
data_negative['Comments'].iloc[:4]
```

[image: result for 4 items]

Use the above code to check the first 4 rows. It looks fine.

**Situation 3**

```
num_word = []
for num in (data_negative['Comments'].iloc[:4].str.split()):
  num_word.append(num)
  print(num_word)
```

[image: 4 items using for loop]

When wanted to just count the number of word in first 4 items, each list is separated by comma and the result is repeating the first row list.

**Questions**

1: Why there is comma in the Comments column while original csv does not have?

2: Where is the error of my code to get num_word ?

**Expected result**

Able to count the num_word

**Dataset**

[Removed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15lKlrnpyaqAJJOGPUl0GzJW0-Cet3j4A/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Each item when you use split is separated into a string and added to the list `num_word`. If you would like to count the number of words I would suggest doing

```
len(num_word)
```

which will give you the length of the list where you split and add the words, If you are looking for frequency

```
from collections import Counter
word_count = Counter(num_word)
```